# Custom template for specific vocabulary term

Tags: 7, theming, taxonomy-terms

Hi guys i hope you can help me with this, i made a vocabulary called Colors and inside this i have the terms: red, green, blue.

I was wondering, how can i make custom templates for each term, for example, for mysite.com/colors/red i want a different template than for mysite.com/colors/blue

I saw that it's possible for nodes, but don't know if it's possible for taxonomies. How can i do this?

Edit: for Drupal 7

Comment: which drupal version?

Comment: Drupal 7 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with the following:

taxonomy-term--**[term id]**.tpl.php You can get the **term id number** when you hover the edit button.

Comment: Thanks, i have to do anything more? add an extra function to template.php maybe?

Comment: thanks, it worked, just had to empty the cache. But there is a problem is not completely overrode, how can i make the template manually without displaying the text "No content for this term" ?